# robot_localization can't locate node - jade upgrade

Tags: navigation, ekf, ros-jade, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I have recently upgraded from indigo to jade, and installed (in ubuntu) the jade `robot_localization` package via apt.

When I do

```
roslaunch robot_localization  ekf_template.launch
```

I get

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_localization/ekf_localization_node]: can't locate node [ekf_localization_node] in package [robot_localization]
```

or if I do

```
rosrun robot_localization ekf_localization_node
```

I get

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named ekf_localization_node below /opt/ros/jade/share/robot_localization
```

I can see the package is installed,
calization
launch$ ls /opt/ros/jade/share/robot_localization/
cmake  launch  LICENSE  package.xml  srv

and it shows in rospack list.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223730/robot_localization-can%27t-locate-node---jade-upgrade/) by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2016-01-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) on 2016-01-09**:
I can also see the executable,
/opt/ros/jade/lib/robot_localization/ekf_localization_node

which if I run directly from the command line, creates an odom/filtered topic.   So looks like the node is installed but something is not set up correctly to know where it is?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-02-05**:
Interesting. Have you tried `rospack profile`? It sounds like something with your environment. Did you just upgrade to jade, and if so, did you `source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash`?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-07-20**:
Is this still a problem, or can this be closed?

**Comment by [ZanaZak](https://answers.ros.org/users/30251/zanazak/) on 2017-10-31**:
I Got the same error. I'm using indigo distribution. I did "source devel/setup.bash" but the same error occurred when typing "roslaunch robot_localization  ekf_template.launch". Please HELP

**Comment by [dylanzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32958/dylanzhang/) on 2017-12-20**:
Hi I am facing the same issue and cannot find a way to solve it. Can I ask you have you found a way to solve this problem? I am using kinetic. Many thanks in advance.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-01-11**:
Any reason why you are running that template? It's just meant to be used as an example. Running it won't do anything. Jade is EOL, but Kinetic is definitely [installing](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/ea36b4fbe74458e07d1fe57cdc3bb7d917f9381d/CMakeLists.txt#L174) those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you have something wrong with your workspaces in general. Try `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, then run your command. If it works, then your workspace overlay is causing trouble.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seth](https://answers.ros.org/users/41187/seth/) on 2019-06-12**:
How to fix this? Because I can access roslaunch robot_localization ekf_template.launch, but which will fail because it is not able to find ekf_localization_node.

I just installed ekf_localizaiton with: sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-robot-localization
and want to be able to access it in my current workspace.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2019-06-13**:
What happens if you follow the steps in my answer? `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, then `roslaunch robot_localization ekf_template.launch`. Does it work? If so, then you need to `catkin clean` your workspace, `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, `catkin build` your workspace, *then* source your workspace `devel/setup.bash` file.

**Comment by [seth](https://answers.ros.org/users/41187/seth/) on 2019-06-13**:
Yes with your answer I see 4 nodes to run: `robot_localization_listener_node, navsat_tranform_node, ukf_localization_node` and `ekf_locallization_node`. But otherwise I only see the first 2. After `catkin clean` I can still only see 2 out of the 4 existing nodes

**Comment by [seth](https://answers.ros.org/users/41187/seth/) on 2019-06-21**:
Maybe I do not understand it correctly, since `catkin_make clean` did not work for me. However creating a new workspace and putting my packages in this new workspace fixed my problems. Thnx for the help =D